# jquery - regex trouble using .match

Tags: jquery, regex

Best explained with an example you can fiddle with:  http://jsfiddle.net/F4H46/

To summarize:

(a) JQuery script is fired by clicking an anchor tag.

(b) Desired result: get chars following the href `id=?` and save to variables

(c) $(this)[0] **does** contain the correct href

(d) Using .match(regex) to strip off the desired chars creates a 404 error.

Why a 404 error?  The .match(regex) works PERFECTLY if the same string is hard-coded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("a").bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  
    var xxx = $(this).attr('href');
    alert(xxx);
    var yyy = xxx.match(/\=(\d*)(\w*)/);
    alert(yyy[0]);
    alert(yyy[1]);
    alert(yyy[2]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click the anchor tag, the page will automatically change the href of the page, causing a 404 cause the page doesn't exist. First thing to do after the anchor tag is clicked is: `e.preventDefault()`, preventing the page from getting redirected.

```
$("a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // rest of the code
});
```

Comment: Oh right! I remember telling myself not to forget preventDefault when I read the api...

Answer (score 0):

Youse this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("a").click(function()
{   var xxx = $(this).attr('href');
        alert(xxx);
    var yyy = xxx.match(/\=(\d*)(\w*)/);
    alert(yyy[0]);
    alert(yyy[1]);
    alert(yyy[2]);
});
</script>
```

This working, difference is that you need to use `attr('href');`